# Python isinstance returns false. Custom class

Tags: python, isinstance

I have written the following code.

```py
class Mammal:
    def info():
        return 'I have fur on my body.'

    def identity_mammal():
        print('I am a mammal')

class Primate(Mammal):
    def info():
        return Mammal.info() + ' I have a large brain.'

    def identity_primate():
        print('I am a primate')

class Ape(Primate):
    def info():
        return Primate.info() + ' I am monkey oooh oooh aaah aaah.'

    def identity_ape():
        print('I am an ape')

class Human(Primate):
    def info():
        return Primate.info() + ' I am human, me bipedal SMART monkey'

    def identity_human():
        print('I am a human')

John = Human

print(isinstance(John, Mammal))
print(isinstance(John, Primate))
print(isinstance(John, Human))
print(isinstance(John, Ape))
```

It is a simple task about inheritance, but when i use the isinstance function, it doesn't seem like the instance of Human i just created is human

```
[iveris@ic-rh7mnifi-105 oblig44]$ python3 inheritance.py 

False
False
False
False
```

Comment: Typo: `John = Human` needs to be `John = Human()`.

Comment: In your own words, what do you expect `John = Human` to do?

Answer (score 1):

To create the instance, you need to use parenthesis:

```
John = Human()

print(isinstance(John, Mammal))
print(isinstance(John, Primate))
print(isinstance(John, Human))
print(isinstance(John, Ape))
```

Comment: but using `John = Human`, and writing `print(John.info())`, I get `I have fur on my body.... etc` printed. Adding a parenthesis when declaring John, does make isinstance work, but makes `print(John.info())` give me an error